# PHP get visitor location by latitude longitude

Tags: php

- I have longitude and latitude stored in my database.
- Is there any function where i can pass both value and get location.

Comment: There are multiple API for  this

Comment: @Master Dev look here http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php this is very powerful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one hope this will help you

```
function get_location($lat, $lon) {

        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" .
                $lat . "," . $lon . "&sensor=false";

        $json = @file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($json);

        $status = $data->status;
        $address = '';

        if ($status == "OK") {

            $address = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
            return $address;
        } else
            return '';
    }

echo get_location($lat, $lon); //function call
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a latitude and longitude stored for a visitor. In order to get a address with these values, you would need to use a third party API to "reverse geocode" the location.

Some options are:

-[Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding)'s Geocoding Services

-[Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/?language=cURL#retrieve-places-near-a-location)'s API

-[OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding) Might have something too.

You could use something like curl to query these API's
Example from Mapbox's Website

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/-73.989,40.733.json?access_token=your-access-token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a modified version of a snippet I found that uses http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php to get its information. Keep in mind, you can also apply for an API key with them and use the API directly to get the information supplied as you see fit. As you can see http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php, they have examples in everything from PHP to JavaScript, to ASP.Net. As noted, below does not require a key as it pulls their public page and Regex's through the page to get specified info. Key's are free.

### Snippet

```
function detect_location($ip=NULL, $asArray=FALSE) {
    if (empty($ip)) {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; }
        else { $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; }
    }
    elseif (!is_string($ip) || strlen($ip) < 1 || $ip == '127.0.0.1' || $ip == 'localhost') {
        $ip = '8.8.8.8';
    }

    $url = 'http://ipinfodb.com/ip_locator.php?ip=' . urlencode($ip);
    $i = 0; $content; $curl_info;

    while (empty($content) && $i < 5) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $curl_opt = array(
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 1,
            CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        );
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) $curl_opt[CURLOPT_USERAGENT] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opt);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        if (!is_null($curl_info)) $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    $araResp = array();
    if (preg_match('{<li>City : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['city'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>State/Province : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['state'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>Country : ([^<]*)}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['country'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>Zip or postal code : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['zip'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>Latitude : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['latitude'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>Longitude : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['longitude'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>Timezone : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['timezone'] = trim($regs[1]);
    if (preg_match('{<li>Hostname : ([^<]*)</li>}i', $content, $regs)) $araResp['hostname'] = trim($regs[1]);

    $strResp = ($araResp['city'] != '' && $araResp['state'] != '') ? ($araResp['city'] . ', ' . $araResp['state']) : 'UNKNOWN';

    return $asArray ? $araResp : $strResp;
}
```

### To Use

```
detect_location();
//  returns "CITY, STATE" based on user IP

detect_location('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
//  returns "CITY, STATE" based on IP you provide

detect_location(NULL, TRUE);    //   based on user IP
//  returns array(8) { ["city"] => "CITY", ["state"] => "STATE", ["country"] => "US", ["zip"] => "xxxxx", ["latitude"] => "xx.xxxxxx", ["longitude"] => "-xx.xxxxxx", ["timezone"] => "-07:00", ["hostname"] => "xx-xx-xx-xx.host.name.net" }

detect_location('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', TRUE);   //   based on IP you provide
//  returns array(8) { ["city"] => "CITY", ["state"] => "STATE", ["country"] => "US", ["zip"] => "xxxxx", ["latitude"] => "xx.xxxxxx", ["longitude"] => "-xx.xxxxxx", ["timezone"] => "-07:00", ["hostname"] => "xx-xx-xx-xx.host.name.net" }
```

## another example from ip-api.com:

<kbd>call.php</kbd>

```
<?php
$ip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the IP address to query
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
  echo 'Hello visitor from '.$query['country'].', '.$query['city'].'!';
} else {
  echo 'Unable to get location';
}
?>
```

and the <kbd>class.php</kbd>:

```
<?php

class IPAPI {
    static $fields = 65535;     // refer to http://ip-api.com/docs/api:returned_values#field_generator
    static $use_xcache = true;  // set this to false unless you have XCache installed (http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)
    static $api = "http://ip-api.com/php/";

    public $status, $country, $countryCode, $region, $regionName, $city, $zip, $lat, $lon, $timezone, $isp, $org, $as, $reverse, $query, $message;

    public static function query($q) {
        $data = self::communicate($q);
        $result = new static;
        foreach($data as $key => $val) {
            $result->$key = $val;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function communicate($q) {
        $q_hash = md5('ipapi'.$q);
        if(self::$use_xcache && xcache_isset($q_hash)) {
            return xcache_get($q_hash);
        }
        if(is_callable('curl_init')) {
            $c = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, self::$api.$q.'?fields='.self::$fields);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result_array = unserialize(curl_exec($c));
            curl_close($c);
        } else {
            $result_array = unserialize(file_get_contents(self::$api.$q.'?fields='.self::$fields));
        }
        if(self::$use_xcache) {
            xcache_set($q_hash, $result_array, 86400);
        }
        return $result_array;
    }
}


// example
$query = IPAPI::query("google.com");
echo 'Country: '.$query->country.', city: '.$query->city;

echo '<br><br>debug: <pre>';
var_dump($query);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```